# How can I speed up reading a CSV/Parquet file from adl:// with fsspec+adlfs?

Tags: python, dask, fsspec

I have a several gigabyte CSV file residing in Azure Data Lake. Using Dask, I can read this file in under a minute as follows:

```py
>>> import dask.dataframe as dd
>>> adl_path = 'adl://...'
>>> df = dd.read_csv(adl_path, storage_options={...})
>>> len(df.compute())
```

However, I don't want to read this into a Dask or Pandas DataFrame -- I want direct access to the underlying file. (Currently it's CSV, but I'd also like to be able to handle Parquet files.) So I am also trying to use [adlfs 0.2.0](https://github.com/dask/adlfs/releases/tag/v0.2.0):

```py
>>> import fsspec
>>> adl = fsspec.filesystem('adl', store_name='...', tenant_id=...)
>>> lines = 0
>>> with adl.open(adl_path) as fh:
>>>    for line in fh:
>>>        lines += 1
```

In the same amount of time as the Dask process, this method has only read in 0.1% of the input.

I've tried using `fsspec`'s caching, thinking that this would speed up access after [the initial caching](https://filesystem-spec.readthedocs.io/en/latest/features.html#caching-files-locally) is done:

```py
>>> fs = fsspec.filesystem("filecache", target_protocol='adl', target_options={...}, cache_storage='/tmp/files/')
>>> fs.exists(adl_path) # False
>>> fs.size(adl_path) # FileNotFoundError

>>> # Using a relative path instead of fully-qualified (FQ) path:
>>> abs_adl_path = 'absolute/path/to/my/file.csv'
>>> fs.exists(abs_adl_path) # True
>>> fs.size(abs_adl_path) # 1234567890 -- correct size in bytes
>>> fs.get(abs_adl_path, local_path) # FileNotFoundError
>>> handle = fs.open(abs_adl_path) # FileNotFoundError
```

Is there a performant way to read CSVs (and also Parquet) remotely as a normal Python filehandle *without* loading as a Dask DataFrame first?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not know why `fs.get` doesn't work, but please try this for the final line:

```
handle = fs.open(adl_path)
```

i.e., you *open* the original path, but you get a file handle to a local file (once the copy is done) somewhere in '/tmp/files/'.

Comment: Using the fully-qualified name (ie, `adl://...`) also doesn't work. I use an unqualified, absolute path in the other examples only because they _do_ work. `.exists` and `.size` both work with the absolute path but not the FQ path. The FQ path doesn't work for any methods I've tried.

Comment: https://github.com/intake/filesystem_spec/pull/245 - please try to install from master after this is merged (shortly)

Comment: I installed from master. Curiously, I now get `fs.size(abs_adl_path) == 4` and `next(fsspec.filesystem("filecache", target_protocol='adl', target_options={...}).open(abs_adl_file)) == b'test'`. Not sure where this `test` value is coming from - it's not in my file.

Comment: Maybe old stuff in /tmp/files?

Comment: There were two files in /tmp/files: `cache` contained some encoded data including the path to my file. (I assume "test" was in there.) There was also another file that contained exactly "test". However, if I delete those files and re-run, they are re-created.

Comment: I don't know :|  `adlfs.open(abs_adl_file).read()` is different? You will need some pdb, I think.

Comment: I blew away the old file, created a new one, and that works fine: initial use of a file caches and completes in a bit over a minute. Subsequent processing is only a few seconds. Thanks!